# What is the htaccess file content if I want redirect subfolder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

My blog path was like this **`http://www.domain.com/blog`**
Now i have created subdomain like **`http://blog.domain.com`**. I want to redirect request from **`http://www.domain.com/blog/?p=123`** to **`http://blog.domain.com/?p=123`**

What should be my .htaccess file content

Answer (score 2):

To [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), you must only specify the original URL path and the target domain. In `www.domain.com`'s document root .htaccess

```
Redirect /blog/ http://blog.domain.com/
```

Since the query string is the same in both cases, there is no need to use `mod_rewrite`.

---

When it works as expected, you may set the status code to `301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)).

```
Redirect 301 /blog/ http://blog.domain.com/
```

Comment: Where I should write this code.. in blog folder(http://blog.domain.com/blog) or on document root(ttp://blog.domain.com/).

Comment: Neither one, because `blog.domain.com` is the target. Put it in the document root's .htaccess of `www.domain.com`.